# Terraform - Automatically create SGs for CloudFront IPs

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I am trying to automatically create SGs for CloudFront IPs so I can associate them my ALB.

[This article](https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2019/03/26/terraform-cloudfront-sg/) has a very good insight on how to achieve it, but unfortunately it didn't work on my environment.

This is the code:

```
data "aws_ip_ranges" "cloudfront" {
  regions = ["global"]
  services = ["cloudfront"]
}

locals {
  chunks_v4 = chunklist(data.aws_ip_ranges.cloudfront.cidr_blocks, 60)
}

resource "aws_security_group" "cloudfront" {
    count = length(local.chunks_v4)

    ingress {
        from_port = 443
        to_port   = 443
        protocol  = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = [local.chunks_v4[count.index]]
    }

    egress {
        from_port = 0
        to_port   = 0
        protocol  = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }
}
```

and that is the error message:

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 34, in resource "aws_security_group" "cloudfront":
│   34:         cidr_blocks = [local.chunks_v4[count.index]]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number, known only after apply
│     │ local.chunks_v4 is a list of list of dynamic, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": element 0: string required.
╵
```

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
local.chunks_v4[count.index][0 to 59???]
```

How can I achieve it by using Terraform?

Comment: OK my bad! I had PyCharm converting the old syntax and it kept the brackets here: ["${local.chunks_v4[count.index]}"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Since there is a hard limit of 60 CIDR blocks, we need to split it into chunks, thanks for the heads up @Marcin!

```
locals {
  chunks_v4 = chunklist(data.aws_ip_ranges.cloudfront.cidr_blocks, 60)
}

data "aws_ip_ranges" "cloudfront" {
  regions  = ["global"]
  services = ["cloudfront"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "cloudfront" {
  count = length(local.chunks_v4)

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = local.chunks_v4[count.index]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you confident that this will work? I think you may hit SG limits with that as I expect lots of IP ranges cloudfront has. Thus OP is trying to overcome the limit, by splitting `data.aws_ip_ranges.cloudfront.cidr_blocks` into small chunks.

Comment: I was concerned about it too, @Marcin but I did apply it in a test AWS account, and worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I know OP's intention is to split it in some chunks, because of that I've asked if OP really needs it, and then, I sent an example.

Comment: I just run it to double check. I get " rules: RulesPerSecurityGroupLimitExceeded: The maximum number of rules per security group has been reached", How many elements do you get in `data.aws_ip_ranges.cloudfront.cidr_blocks`?

Comment: Not sure but I can try again since I've deleted it, but if it is not working in your setup and since OP said he found a solution, I'm going to delete this answer and I can send my output in his first comment, sounds good? :) -- just to avoid bad information there.

Comment: No reason to delete. I think its good answer. Maybe just a small note about the limit would be useful.

Comment: My test rerturns 76 ciders. Default limit is 60. So I get error. Maybe in your case you get different ciders or you have increased limit.

Comment: I got the same but with no error, terraform went well. `Inbound rules (76)` I'll make a note about that limit. Thanks for the help @Marcin!

Comment: done! feel free to edit to include more information, It is 04:00am here, hehe. Thank you for the help @Marcin!

Comment: @no problem. Looks good.